# TypeError: unorderable types: float() < str() while using fit_transform of LabelBinarizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to handle a categorical field of a pandas DataFrame using LabelBinarizer from scikit-learn.

While doing so I am getting an error

> "TypeError: unorderable types: float() < str()"

You can see below `train_data['embarked']` is a categorical field and it contains only 3 values. But while I am using `LabelBinarizer` I am getting the mentioned error

```
train_data['embarked'].head()

train_data['embarked'].value_counts()

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
labelbinarizer = LabelBinarizer()
lb_result = labelbinarizer.fit_transform(train_data["embarked"])
```

The output of the first two lines is as below.

```
0    S
1    C
2    S
3    S
4    S

Name: embarked, dtype: object

S    644
C    168
Q     77
Name: embarked, dtype: int64
```

The last line causing the error. The entire error message looks like below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    lb_result = labelbinarizer.fit_transform(train_data["embarked"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py", line 307, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(y).transform(y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py", line 276, in fit
    self.y_type_ = type_of_target(y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py", line 284, in type_of_target
    if (len(np.unique(y)) > 2) or (y.ndim >= 2 and len(y[0]) > 1):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 264, in unique
    ret = _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 312, in _unique1d
    ar.sort()
TypeError: unorderable types: float() < str()
```

What is the issue with this piece of code I am unable to understand?

Answer (score 0):

Use `astype('str')`

```py
lb_result = labelbinarizer.fit_transform(train_data["embarked"].astype('str'))
```